# MySQL Delete older records

Tags: mysql

I have thousands of records (included duplicate posts) so now I want to delete old records (just leave the latest record) based on date.

My code is given below

```
DELETE a.*
FROM dle_post AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM dle_post
      GROUP BY title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.title = a.title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
```

The problem is that it random records base on `ID`. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I assume latest version of a post will have the biggest ID, so you should use Max insteas of Min to chose which ID will be saved

Comment: @StefanoZanini Thank you, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to base it on date, you should use `MAX(date)` in the subquery.

```
DELETE a.*
FROM dle_post AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT title, MAX(date) AS maxdate
      FROM dle_post
      GROUP BY title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b 
ON b.title = a.title
AND a.date < b.maxdate
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Just create the `SELECT` query of posts you want to delete and put and in a subselect:

```
DELETE FROM dle_post WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM dle_post WHERE ... )
```

This is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: That will get an error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: OK. I have been using PostgreSQL a lot and I think there I can do this there. I learned something today.

Comment: Also, it should be `NOT IN`, since he wants to delete all but the latest record in each group.

Comment: It's an annoying restriction that MySQL has.

Comment: I still leave my answer, as the answer you referred to also gives some ideas on how to address the issue.